# Jquery Queued request with time

Tags: jquery, ajax, queue

I have a form for send messages to users of a forum. These messages are sent every 35 seconds (Security Policy Forum) with jQuery $.ajax post request...

I put name and text for the message in the input and textarea corresponding. The method I want to do:

1-click in the button "Send", make request with user and text for the forum message.

2-click in the button "Send", make request with user and text for the forum message.

3-click in the button "Send", make request with user and text for the forum message.

4-click in the button "Send", make request with user and text for the forum message.

5-......

These four requests or more are in the queue at same time. But,

I need to run the first request and wait 35 seconds

After run the second request and wait 35 seconds

After run the tirth request and wait 35 seconds

After run the fourth request and wait 35 seconds

....

Sorry my English is not good.

Thanks for the replies

Comment: You can maintain an array that's refreshed every time a click is made and pushed into the array AND every 35 minutes when the next request is process and shifted out of the array.

Comment: how I do this? Please ;)

Comment: Show us some sample HTML ( button ) and your code (JS).

Comment: I got nothing done. Just point and load and unload data array in x seconds. Thanks ;)

Comment: See logic in my answer below. *The logic* should give you a good idea on what to do.

Comment: I have added a rough demo that you could use for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any code to work with here is my suggestion. You will create and maintain an array containing all the pertinent information required to make an ajax call that will send a message.

The array gets updated with an additional item each time a qualifying click is made. The first click (*any click made when array is empty*) starts off the counter. Once each request in the array (*the first element*), that element is removed from the array using the `.shift()` method. If the array is empty, the counter is stopped.

```
$(function() {
    var requests = [],
        sender,
        url = 'url-to-send-ajax-call-to';

    //Have as many of these as the number of different buttons the user may click
    $('button').on('click', scheduleRequest);

    function scheduleRequest() {
        //in here 'this' references the button that was clicked
        //if it contains data, use it.
        requests.push({
            something:$(this).data('something')/*data from button*/,
            email:'ab@c.com',
            message:'whatever other parameters you want to send'
        });

        //if setInterval is not running
        if( !sender ) {
            //fire it up and store a reference to it
            sender = setInterval(sendRequest, 35000);
        }
    }

    function sendRequest() {
        $.post( url, requests[ 0 ], function( data ) {
            requests.shift(); // remove request just processed
            //if no more requests        
            if( requests.length === 0 ) {
                //stop setInterval
                clearInterval( sender );
                sender = undefined;
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            // Do something if call fails
        });
    }
});
```

Something like this. Hope this gives you an idea on how to proceed.

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/3T2jh/)

Comment: WoWWW!! It's perfect for me and works very fine!! Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks ;)